# Kernel in PenalizedSVM R package

Tags: r, svm, feature-selection, lasso

There is not option to select kernel in [penalizedSVM](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/penalizedSVM/index.html) R package. What kernel do they use?
Is there some other R package with penalized SVM methods where I can choose various kernels?